# Bootstrap form label width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form nested in a div.container col-sm-4 when before the sm view snaps the label overlaps the form. I can just change the col size of the label but I the label will change with jquery.

How can I avoid this overlapping?
[image]

http://codepen.io/lpoulter/pen/vzrmk

```
<div class="container area col-sm-4" id="settingsArea" >
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="settingsForm" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="labelRename" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input id="labelRename" name="labelRename" placeholder="Type your question" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try this <div class="container area col-sm-8" id="settingsArea" >
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="settingsForm" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="labelRename" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Question</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input id="labelRename" name="labelRename" placeholder="Type your question" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

Comment: thanks but that still has the same overlap affect. Also i don't really want to change the container size.

Comment: for smaller resolution is it still have a problem ???

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for sm breakpoint. try re-sizing your browser and you will see. http://codepen.io/lpoulter/pen/vzrmk